# how to solve time module in ubuntu

Tags: python-3.x

```
from functools import wraps
from functools import time

def func(any_fuc):
  @wraps(any_fuc)
  def func2(*args,**kwargs):
    print('this is functions run time')
    any_fuc(*args,**kwargs)
  return func2


@func
t1 = time.time()
def new_func(a,b):
  return a+b

print(new_func(1,3))

t2 = time.time()
print(t2-t1)






@func
t1 = time.time()
def new_func(a,b):
  return a+b

print(new_func(1,3))

t2 = time.time()
print(t2-t1)
```

error :

```
  File "main.py", line 13
    t1 = time.time()
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

```

Comment: You are doing `from functools import time`, but it should probably just be `import time`.

Answer (score 0):

Decorators are not allowed before assignment statements.  Decorators are allowed only before function definitions, class definitions, and coroutine definitions.  You can read more about decorators [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function) and [here](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-decorator)

```
t1 = time.time()

@func
def new_func(a,b):
  return a+b
```